# How does reducer can work with an object with duplicate keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Learning React with Redux, the course author wrote this:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_STREAM:
      return { ...stream, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case CREATE_STREAM:
      return { ...stream, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case EDIT_STREAM:
      return { ...stream, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

As much as I understood, the `{ ...stream, [action.payload.id]: action.payload }` pattern is a new `JavaScript` syntax called **"Key Interpolation Syntax"** and what it does is that it **adds** a new `key/value` to our object ( which we have made a copy of it with `spread ...` syntax first ) so in that case I do understand the `CREATE_STREAM` one, but how about `EDIT_STREAM` ? Is it gonna **replace** the key because the key is already in there? or is it gonna blindly add it so then duplicate key? Also I don't understand the `FETCH_STREAM` at all.  Why is it even like this? Shouldn't it just be a `return action.payload` ?

Comment: But all cases are the same?

Comment: Objects cannot have duplicate keys. If the `action.payload.id` already exists as a key in `stream`, it will be overwritten / replaced by the latter `action.payload` value.

Comment: @Phil : Thanks. Understood. How about the "FETCH" one that we are just getting ONE record ? Why is he doing it like that returning all the items?

Comment: @UnskilledCoder don't know, we'd need a lot more context but also, that's probably too broad a question for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the Key Interpolation syntax will add that key if it doesn't exist but will override its value if it is duplicated.

The following code

```js
const personA = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 42
};

const createdProp = 'country';
const overriddenProp = 'age';

const personB = {
  ...personA,
  [createdProp]: 'USA',
  [overriddenProp]: 50
};
```

Will result in `personB` with these values

```js
{
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 50,
  country: "USA"
}
```

About the `FETCH` it depends on what they intended. If the spread operation is removed, then all previous data will be lost. If that is no problem, you can do `{ [action.payload.id]: action.payload }` without worries.

Comment: Thanks. Understood. How about the "FETCH" one that we are just getting ONE record ? Why is he doing it like that returning all the items?